# Angular 2.0.0 - Mock File Uploader

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I am using ng2-file-upload. How do I mock its FileUploader class in unit testing?

```
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '...',
  providers: [ MyService ]
})

export class MyComponent {
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: '/my-app/api/upload',
              authToken: 'token'});
constructor() {
  this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item:any, response: any, headers: any) => {
    console.log('how to test here');
  }
}
```

I am having a hard time mocking it in my spec. Please help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a file upload component that I have build and am trying to port this https://www.noppanit.com/javascript-tdd-on-file-upload/ over to my spec.ts. I've just seen on another resource that spyOn is only available if you have the Typing for Jasmine. In the process of setting that up. I'll keep you posted (I think spyOn is the solution though).

Comment: @TerryBarriff Thank you. I also have a problem testing it since I have overriden some of the ng2-file-upload FileUploader functions. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: have you checked my answer? Has it helped?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. I will test it soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to reply to your comment, but I think the following may help to answer your original question on how to mock the FileUploader class taken from their unit test from the file [file-drop.directive.spec.ts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/development/components/file-upload/file-drop.directive.spec.ts):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { inject, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FileUploader } from './file-uploader.class';
import { FileUploadModule } from './file-upload.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'container',
  template: `<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />`
})
export class ContainerComponent {
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: 'localhost:3000'});
}

describe('Directive: FileSelectDirective', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FileUploadModule],
      declarations: [ContainerComponent],
      providers: [ContainerComponent]
    });
  });

  it('should be fine', inject([ContainerComponent], (fixture:ComponentFixture<ContainerComponent>) => {
    expect(fixture).not.toBeNull();
  }));
});
```

Where `import { FileUploader } from './file-uploader.class';` is how you import the FileUploader into your test, `ContainerComponent` is imported into the test itself.

Further to this, I have created a dummy file to test with on my component, but I am still writing it!

```js
it('should accept a file for upload', () => {
    var modifiedDate = new Date();
    var file = new File([3555], 'test-file.jpg', {lastModified : modifiedDate, type: 'image/jpeg'});
    FileUploadComponent.upload(file);
});
```

To test if this works, I have a metadata model that I expect to be populated upon the file being selected. I can therefore make two assertions, that both the upload input box will have a file and that the metadata object will be populated.

In the case of ng2-file-upload, I beleive the file list will be populated allowing you to check that the test file has been imported into that.

Good luck!

Comment: @terrybariff I'm still having problems as I have overriden the functions of the FileUploader. How can I test them? I will update the question.